# Linq inner join into group, then selecting group, why are there empty groups?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I'm trying to get a list of customers with their respective orders, but if a customer doesn't have any orders they should be excluded from this list.

```
        var customerOrders = (from customer in customers
            join order in orders on customer.CustomerId equals order.CustomerId into
                orderGroup
            select new
            {
                Customer.CustomerId,
                Orders = orderGroup.ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

In the customerOrders list, I'm getting customers with no orders or with empty Orders list.

How can I only get the customers with orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where orderGroup.Any()`:

```
var customerOrders =
(
    from customer in customers
    join order in orders on customer.CustomerId equals order.CustomerId into orderGroup
    where orderGroup.Any()
    select new
    {
        customer.CustomerId,
        Orders = orderGroup.ToList()
    }
).ToList();
```

Or `group order by customer.CustomerId into g`:

```
var customerOrders =
(
    from customer in customers
    join order in orders on customer.CustomerId equals order.CustomerId
    group order by customer.CustomerId into g
    select new
    {
        CustomerId = g.k,
        Orders = g.ToList()
    }
).ToList();
```